# Quote and Parallel

Tags: formatting, quoting, parallel

I'm trying to set 2 texts - one is the original, one is the translation - side by side in a quote. I use the parallelpackage and a redefined quote:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\singlespacing\small}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quotation\expandafter{\quotation\singlespacing\small}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1]
%\begin{quote}
  \begin{Parallel}{.45\linewidth}{.45\linewidth}
    \ParallelLText{ \lipsum[1] }
    \ParallelRText{ \lipsum[1] }
  \end{Parallel}
%\end{quote}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

First: Latex tells me: ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
Second: The Parallel environment somehow does not use a proper right margin, so the quote always goes above said margin.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example, not a code fragment.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your redefinition?

Comment: Sorry, edited for minimal working example. I want the parallel text in a quote environment (or at least that it looks like a quote environment) meaning that the margin should change. The redefinition is just for smaller quotes with singlespacing

Comment: Are your quotes likely to span pages?

Comment: No, just a half of a page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a `minipage` environment for the quotation. This has the drawback that minipages cannot break across pages, which might be too limiting.

### Simple version with `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newenvironment{parquote}
{\begin{center}\singlespacing\small%
\begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}}
{\end{minipage}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{parquote}
  \begin{Parallel}{.45\linewidth}{.45\linewidth}
    \ParallelLText{ \lipsum[1] }
    \ParallelRText{ \lipsum[1] }
  \end{Parallel}
\end{parquote}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Fancier version using `tcolorbox`

Here's a version that will break across pages, using the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{breakable,colframe=white,colback=white,fontupper=\small\singlespacing}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{Parallel}{.45\linewidth}{.45\linewidth}
    \ParallelLText{ \lipsum[1] }
    \ParallelRText{ \lipsum[1] }
  \end{Parallel}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That helped and should be enough for my purposes! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Latex_makes_me_angry Just in case, I've added a splittable version too.

Comment: @alan-Mann thx so much! I ended up using tabularx at last, although im very happy with your solution! Here's my final version using tabularx: https://imgur.com/a/p7kOw